# QGIS splits line feature at all intersections?

Tags: qgis, splitting, linestring

I have a long GPS track that I've converted to a shape file. I need to divide it into segments. The first time I use the "split features" tool, it makes a cut where I draw my line, *but also splits the line into separate features **at every intersection**.*

So suddenly I go from having 1 feature, to having 1000... I don't want this, I want to split my one line feature into two at the point I chose. NOT a every intersection.

Is there a setting somewhere I'm missing, or should I file a bug report?